# dynamic adding of checkbox and input box jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
    for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(value.material).length; i++) {
        var newRow = $('<tr/>');
        newRow.append('<td ><input type="checkbox" class="" name="[]" CHECKED/>Others</td><td><input type="text" value="' + value.material + '" class="" id="' + i + '"><button class="">Delete</button></td>');
    }
$("#tbl > tbody > tr:last").after(newRow);
```

Supposed i have this kind of dynamic adding how can i prevent the first loop from adding the delete button. The reason for this is because the default screen has one row without the button and when i dynamically add these new rows i delete the first one. So i need the first dynamically added row to have no button so that it will look like i only added button and i did not delete the first one.

Comment: Put a if condition for `i==0`

Comment: can you explain a bit more and show which line i should i add it to.

Comment: How would you set the value of an input to an object ?

Comment: @adeneo did i do that? if i did where i will remove it if i am wrong in doing that

Comment: You did, you're using `Object.keys(value.material)` so it's clearly an object, then later on you're concatenating `value.material` into the string as a value ?

Comment: @adeneo i was only using `Object.keys(value.material)'s` length in order to see how many iteration i need then i have the value for `value.material` i put it into the text box. i got the value of `value.material` from this `$.each( array, function( key, value ) {`

Comment: There is no `each` in your code, you're using `value.material` as both an object *and*  a string ?

Comment: sorry i did not include the `each` as i thought it is not relevant to the question. `value.material` is a string and its value is place in the textbox

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74477/discussion-between-pekka-and-adeneo).

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the first row from having button, check if `i===0` in the loop,

```
for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(value.material).length; i++) {
        var newRow = $('<tr/>');
        if(i===0) {
         newRow.append('<td ><input type="checkbox" class="" name="[]" CHECKED/>Others</td><td><input type="text" value="' + value.material + '" class="" id="' + i + '">');

        } else {
        newRow.append('<td ><input type="checkbox" class="" name="[]" CHECKED/>Others</td><td><input type="text" value="' + value.material + '" class="" id="' + i + '"><button class="">Delete</button></td>');
        }
    }
```

Comment: correct me if i am wrong if i do it like this when `for` continues to iterate `var i` will increment then i will go to else because var i is no longer `==` to `0` then i will generate the row with button

Comment: then i return to my original problem i want first row to have no button

Comment: Initially `i` will be `0` so it will not contain any button. Then in next iteration `i` will be ` so after this all other rows will have buttons

Comment: After first iteration only `i` will increment

Comment: actually i tried it the first row still have button let me check maybe i got something wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(value.material).length; i++) {
    var newRow = $('<tr/>');
    newRow.append('<td ><input type="checkbox" class="" name="[]" CHECKED/>Others</td><td><input type="text" value="' + value.material + '" class="" id="' + i + '">' + (i == 0 ? '' : '<button class="">Delete</button></td>'));
}
$("#tbl > tbody > tr:last").after(newRow);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use more jQuery ?

```
$("#tbl > tbody > tr:last").after(function () {
    var i = 0;
    return $.map(value.material, function (val, key) {
        var row    = $('<tr />'),
            cell1  = $('<td />'),
            cell2  = $('<td />'),
            inp1   = $('<input />', {
                type    : 'checkbox',
                name    : '[]',
                checked : 'checked'
            }),
            inp2   = $('<input />', {
                type  : 'text',
                value : val,
                id    : i
            }),
            button = $('<button />', {
                text : 'Delete'
            });

        return row.append(
            cell1.append(inp1), 
            cell2.append(inp2, (i++ !== 0 ? button : []))
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: Could use some explanation

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(value.material).length; i++) 
    {
       var newRow = '<tr>';
       newRow += '<td ><input type="checkbox" class="" name="[]" CHECKED/>Others</td><td><input type="text" value="' + value.material + '" class="" id="' + i + '">';

       if(i != 0)
         newRow += '<button class="">Delete</button>'

       newRow += '</td></tr>'
    }
    $("#tbl > tbody > tr:last").after(newRow);
```